# Spring Boot - Key Store Password set in Code

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, keystore

**Spring Boot Version:** 1.5.4.RELEASE

I'm currently having an issue with setting my `server.ssl.key-store-password` within the code of my Spring Boot application. We store our passwords in a vault, and I was previously passing it in via a `-D` property. This, however, isn't an ideal solution for us.

The solution *seemed* simple, and below is what I did:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
    final String keyStorePassword;
    // ... Get Password
    return servletContext -> servletContext.setInitParameter("server.ssl.key-store-password", keyStorePassword);
}
```

According to the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) this should be fine, as the `ServletConfig` is loaded *before* the `application.properties`.

Unfortunately, Tomcat refuses to start with the `server.ssl.key-store-password` set in this way. From what I can see, the `AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor` constructs an `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Ssl` object which is fed to Tomcat, and used to construct the keystore. This is done during `SpringApplication.run()`, which is obviously prior to construction of the `ServletConfig` bean.

So it seems that I need to 'refresh' the context (which from what I understand is destroying/recreating it), or find another approach. I *could* set the property using something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String keyStorePassword = getKeystorePassword();
    HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("server.ssl.key-store-password", keyStorePassword);
    new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(TesterApplication.class)
            .properties(props)
            .run(args);
}
```

This has its own problems though. I was thinking of storing the 'label' for the vault password in my application.yml, but if I do so, then I don't have access to that label before Spring has started (without manually parsing the application.yml, which poses its own problems with multiple profiles).

Has anyone else encountered a solution to this issue? Perhaps my approach is wrong, and there's a simpler way of doing things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, figured it out. Was on the wrong track. What I should have done was the following:

```
@Component
public class KeystoreInit {

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public KeystoreInit(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
        final ServerProperties serverProperties = new ServerProperties();
        final Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
        final String keystorePassword = getKeystorePassword();
        ssl.setKeyPassword(keystorePassword);
        System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password", keystorePassword);
        serverProperties.setSsl(ssl);
        return serverProperties;
    }

    private String getKeystorePassword() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

The idea here is that we're creating the initial `ServerProperties` bean. This bean is then loaded instead of a fresh `ServerProperties`, so our `Ssl` with the keystore password is set there already. This isn't overridden since we don't set `server.ssl.key-store-password` in our `application.yml`.

We `@Autowire` the `Environment` so that we can access out `server.ssl.key-store-label` property (which I had previously created), use that to load our actual `server.ssl.key-store-password` property, and then set that via System properties so that it can be accessed elsewhere in the application.

Comment: I just don't get why you need to Autowire Environment and then not using it

Comment: The autowired Environment is used in the omitted `getKeystorePassword()` method.

Answer (score 4):

- spring boot:2.3.1.RELEASE
- you need to add `@Primary` at method otherwise it will Start error.What I should have done was the following:

```java
@Component
public class KeystoreInit {

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public KeystoreInit(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
        final ServerProperties serverProperties = new ServerProperties();
        final Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
        final String keystorePassword = getKeystorePassword();
        ssl.setKeyPassword(keystorePassword);
        System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password", keystorePassword);
        serverProperties.setSsl(ssl);
        return serverProperties;
    }

    private String getKeystorePassword() {
        // ...
    }
}
```